# Detecting carriage returns in data and printing html code, in 2 types

Tags: php

(Best method I think is with implode/explode function)- I'm trying to learn the implode and explode functions but I can't grasp the syntax with my brain; I need more code examples so I understand more. Examples I find in google are not helping me much. I'm trying to create a function that reads data and displays html. If the data has lines with 1 or less carriage return the line is surrounded by span tag(s) only. If the data has 2 or more carriage returns the lines are first surrounded by span then that group of lines is surrounded by a div tag (with unique id number added to id name if possible.).

Example output with 2 or more carriage returns:

```
<div id="div1">
<span class="class">words group 1</span>
<span class="class">words group 1</span>
<span class="class">words group 1</span>
</div>
<div id="div2">
<span class="class">words group 2</span>
<span class="class">words group 2</span>
</div>
<div id="div3">
<span class="class">words group 3</span>
<span class="class">words group 3</span>
</div>
```

Example output with 1 or less carriage returns:

```
<span class="class">words 0</span>
<span class="class">words 1</span>
<span class="class">words 2</span>
<span class="class">words 3</span>
```

Example data:

```
Hello world
Hello world

Hello world
Hello world
Hello world
Hello world

Hello world

Hello world
Hello world
```

Normally you would need to search the lines for example:

```
"\n"
```

Comment: By definition, no line can contain a Carriage-Return symbol - these symbols always sit **between** individual lines.

Comment: Please add  "data" example

Comment: That's correct the returns are between each line. See example above...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file data content:

```
words group 1.1
words group 1.2
words group 1.3

words group 2.1
words group 2.2

words group 3.1
words group 3.2
```

You can code this way

```
<?php

$last_is_line_empty = true;

foreach(file('data.txt') as $line) {

    $is_line_empty  =  strlen($line)<2 ? true : false;
    $l = chop($line);

    if ($last_is_line_empty && !$is_line_empty){
        echo "<div>\n";
        echo "<span>$l</span>\n";
    }
    if (!$last_is_line_empty && !$is_line_empty){
        echo "<span>$l</span>\n";
    }
    if (!$last_is_line_empty && $is_line_empty){
        echo "</div>\n";
    }

    $last_is_line_empty = $is_line_empty;

}
?>
```

output:

```
<div>
<span>words group 1.1</span>
<span>words group 1.2</span>
<span>words group 1.3</span>
</div>
<div>
<span>words group 2.1</span>
<span>words group 2.2</span>
</div>
<div>
<span>words group 3.1</span>
<span>words group 3.2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: If I read this correct, this is counting the lines right? With the greater than symbol. Seems cool. I will need to test to see if I can make it work with my data. Might function. Not sure yet. :)

Comment: Basically checks the line and previous line. Those lines can be  empty , or not empty . So the if condition decides when echo  something or onother .  No lines counting .